# Modular Arithmetic - two notations of congruence modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I have found that if,

> a ≡ b (mod m)

then

> b ≡ a (mod m)

The meaning of *a ≡ b (mod m)* is that *m | (a-b)* 
& the meaning of *b ≡ a (mod m)*  is that *m | (b-a)*
but , *(a-b)* is opposite to *(b-a)*
So , are we taking only the absolute value of the differences between a & b when we are dealing with congruence modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b \mid a$ means there's $c$ such that $a = b c$. Then $-a = b (-c)$, so that $b \mid -a$.

Answer (score 2):

For any integers $r,s$, we have $r\mid s$ $\iff$ $r\mid-s$.

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv b\mod m$ can also be translated as

> $a$ and $b$, divided by $c$, have the same remainder.

Hence the congruence relation is obviously reflexive, symmetric and transitive.